# Segfault outside of my own code — how can I find the error?

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, openscenegraph

I currently try to get some simple 3D scene displayed in my Qt 4.8 program. A library that is available both on Ubuntu and openSUSE is [OpenSceneGraph](http://www.openscenegraph.org/). I downloaded the [QOsgWidget](https://github.com/kintel/QOsgWidget) class and added it to my program. During runtime I open a new window and add a default constructed instance of `QOsgWidget` to the layout of that `QWidget`. It crashes directly in debug build. When I run it in `gdb`, I can see the new open window which seems to have a “hole” in it, I can see my background picture, but that does not update when I move the window.

When I tried to get the backtrace, I got nothing that links the error to any of my code:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fffcdd68f4f in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so
#1  0x00007fffcdcf6bd0 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so
#2  0x00007fffed0e15ae in osgUtil::RenderStage::drawImplementation(osg::RenderInfo&, osgUtil::RenderLeaf*&) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libosgUtil.so.100
#3  0x00007fffed0e0587 in osgUtil::RenderStage::drawInner(osg::RenderInfo&, osgUtil::RenderLeaf*&, bool&) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libosgUtil.so.100
#4  0x00007fffed0e244f in osgUtil::RenderStage::draw(osg::RenderInfo&, osgUtil::RenderLeaf*&) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libosgUtil.so.100
#5  0x00007fffed0ea32c in osgUtil::SceneView::draw() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libosgUtil.so.100
#6  0x00007ffff518a837 in osgViewer::Renderer::draw() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libosgViewer.so.100
#7  0x00007ffff4b70f19 in osg::GraphicsContext::runOperations() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libosg.so.100
#8  0x00007ffff4bc1da8 in osg::OperationThread::run() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libosg.so.100
#9  0x00007ffff4b73158 in osg::GraphicsThread::run() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libosg.so.100
#10 0x00007fffecda5718 in OpenThreads::ThreadPrivateActions::StartThread(void*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenThreads.so.20
#11 0x00007ffff34f96aa in start_thread (arg=0x7fffca55b700) at pthread_create.c:333
#12 0x00007ffff3816eed in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:109
```

This is the code where I create the instance:

In the file `window3d.h`:

```
#include "QOsgWidget.h"

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
    class Window3D;
}

class Window3D : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT

  public:
    explicit Window3D(QWidget *parent,
                      const std::vector<std::vector<Circles>> &all_circles);
    ~Window3D();

  private:
    Ui::Window3D *ui;
    const std::vector<std::vector<Circles>> &all_circles;
    QOsgWidget osg;
};
```

And the corresponding source:

```
#include "window3d.h"
#include "ui_window3d.h"

Window3D::Window3D(QWidget *parent,
                   const std::vector<std::vector<Circles>> &all_circles)
    : QWidget(parent), ui(new Ui::Window3D), all_circles{all_circles} {
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Window3D::~Window3D() {
    delete ui;
}
```

The main window class has a menu action slot which looks like this:

```
void MainWindow::open_3d() {
    window_3d.reset(new Window3D(nullptr, sm.all_circles));
    window_3d->show();
}
```

The member `window_3d` is a `std::unique_ptr<Window3D>`.

Since I am not really doing anything except using the downloaded `QOsgWidget` and creating an instance of it, I do not understand why it would crash.

Is there a way to get closer to the error with the debugging tools or do I need to find this error somewhere in the OpenSceneGraph documentation?

---

I see that there are different error messages each time I let the application run in debug mode. I added output at the beginnings of the functions to show whether it is working at all. This run crashed with SIGSEGV:

```
QOsgWidget::ctor
QOsgWidget::setupContext()
QOsgWidget::frame()
QOsgWidget::frame()
QOsgWidget::frame()
QOsgWidget::frame()
QOsgWidget::frame()
QOsgWidget::frame()
```

I tried again, and after the following output the window was actually showing, although I could not close it:

```
QOsgWidget::ctor
QOsgWidget::setupContext()
QOsgWidget::frame()
QOsgWidget::frame()
```

The next time I get SIGABRT:

```
QOsgWQOsgWidget::ctor
QOsgWidget::setupContext()
QOsgWidget::frame()
QOsgWidget::frame()
QOsgWidget::frame()
QOsgWidget::frame()
[xcb] Unknown request in queue while dequeuing
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
megrama-qt: ../../src/xcb_io.c:179: dequeue_pending_request: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_unknown_req_in_deq' failed.idget::frame()
```

On the next run I get another SIGSEGV, this time with more `frame()` calls

```
QOsgWidget::ctor
QOsgWidget::setupContext()
QOsgWidget::frame()
QOsgWidget::frame()
QOsgWidget::frame()
QOsgWidget::frame()
QOsgWidget::frame()
QOsgWidget::frame()
QOsgWidget::frame()
QOsgWidget::frame()
QOsgWidget::frame()
QOsgWidget::frame()
QOsgWidget::frame()
QOsgWidget::frame()
QOsgWidget::frame()
QOsgWidget::frame()
QOsgWidget::frame()
QOsgWidget::frame()
QOsgWidget::frame()
QOsgWidget::frame()
QOsgWidget::frame()
```

The random nature of this looks like a threading problem.

---

When I compile the project from the GitHub repository, it compiles using Qt 5 on my system but also crashes with a SIGSEGV on my system.

Comment: Since the only thing you're doing is creating an instance, the question is *how* are you creating that instance? Post the code.

Comment: Sure, I added the source code of the class.

Comment: Possible scenarios: 1. the widget you're using has a bug. 2. You're missing initialization step. 3. Configuration quirk that triggers the crash. I do not think there's easy way around it and most likely you'll need to debug someone else's code, understand why it crashes(or - worst case scenario - how it works) and develop workaround for that or fix the problem. It isn't exactly fun, but it is usual thing while programming. At least you have source code.

Comment: @SigTerm: As I just have updated my question, the sample from the GitHub repo also segfaults when I run it on its own. So the thing itself has a bug. So it looks like scenario (1) of your list.

Comment: Well, in this case you'll need to debug it and fix it yourself or write your own component. IIRC OpenSceneGraph simply provides object hierarchy so you should be able to plug it into QGLWidget if you want to, without using their widgets.

Comment: Have you tried subclassing from QOsgWidget or initializing it on the heap with your Widget as parent?